# Angular get route params from nested dynamic routes

Tags: angular

My url is something like that: 'localhost:4200/mypage/extrainfo'

I want to get '/mypage/' part.

```
ngOnInit() {
const mypage = this.route.snapshot.params.mypage;
}
```

Comment: you want to get `:extra` value?

Comment: I want to get :mypage value only. I've tried couple of things but still doesn't work. :(

Comment: check this [example](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-6-routing-yhgq9c?file=src%2Fapp%2Fpage%2Fservice.component.ts).

Comment: please share your `Router` configuration

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you import ActivatedRoute, you can get your route parameters using the params Observable in the ActivatedRoute.

```
constructor(private route : ActivatedRoute) {

    this.route.params.subscribe((params: any) => {
       console.log(params.mypage);
    });
}
```

Comment: still undefined :(

Comment: try the above code but not in the constructor of your page, try to put this code in ngOnInit()